# Set proper margins for different alphabets?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Some alphabets take bigger spaces than the others when displaying, so how to get the white space in a situation like below to be properly auto adjusted?

In this piece of code, what will be the way to auto adjust the margin between '#re1' and '#re2? So that I won't have the situation below,

[image]

[image]

If I set the margin based on the alphabet 'm', then the white space in between is too big for my purpose when I type 'a'.

```js
function tx() {
  var x = document.getElementById("123").value;
  document.getElementsByClassName("re")[0].innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementsByClassName("re")[1].innerHTML = x;
}
```

```css
#re1 {
  width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  height: 20px;
}

#re2 {
  width: 150px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <body>
    <textarea id="123" onKeyUp="tx();" onKeyPress="tx();" maxlength="23"></textarea><br>
    <div class="out">
      <div class="re" id="re1">1</div>
      <div class="re" id="re2">2</div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you are approaching the problem correctly. You need to define the space between the re1 and re2 divs in such a way that the content inside should not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `line-height` .

```js
function tx() {
  var x = document.getElementById("123").value;
  document.getElementsByClassName("re")[0].innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementsByClassName("re")[1].innerHTML = x;
}
```

```css
#re1 {
  width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 110%;
}

#re2 {
  width: 150px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 110%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="123" onKeyUp="tx();" onKeyPress="tx();" maxlength="23"></textarea><br>
  <div class="out">
    <div class="re" id="re1">1</div>
    <div class="re" id="re2">2</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I still need to define the space in between. But I found the solution now with using the percentage for line-height in combine :). Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

try this snippet:

```
#re1 {
position:relative;      //add
width: 200px;           //remove
word-wrap: break-word;
height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I now found the solution in my  case with using your advice in combine :) Thank you!